# Speech Pathologists and the International Phonetic Alphabet

Tags: ipa, spoken-language

Do speech therapists and speech pathologists have to learn the International Phonetic Alphabet as part of their profession? They might want to learn it, but my question really is: are they required to learn it?

Comment: Are you asking about legal requirements, or practical requirements (e.g. an engineer effectively "has to" know calculus)?

Comment: In my country (Brazil) speech pathologists took basic phonetics classes with us linguists, as a required first-year subject in their undergraduate course.  So I expect speech pathologists are required to learn it in order to graduate.  They probably also study their own [extensions to the IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_to_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet) after doing basic phonetics.

Comment: Speech pathology is treated as applied linguistics in every country where I'm familiar with the training of speech pathologists. Particularly with phonetics; they have to know phonetics **really** well, because they deal with it clinically every day.

Comment: We cannot answer the question unless you specify the answers to 1) Required by whom? 2) Required for what purpose? And possibly (depending on the answers to 1 and 2): 3) In what jursidiction?

Comment: There is one further point that needs to be clarified: learn how well? Generally, phoneticians have to learn the IPA totally save for the disordered extensions; linguists have to learn errrm 50% of it; I believe that SPHS students only have to learn the English subset (and maybe the disordered extension, depending on institution). That would differ in France, Germany, Greece, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the speech pathology curriculum and not linguistics.

Answer (score 4):

Before I retired (7 years ago) I taught a linguistics course in articulatory phonetics from time to time.  About half my class were undergraduate majors in Speech Pathology.  So that course was clearly a requirement for Speech Path at that time.

I used IPA in the course, but there was never a requirement to learn IPA.  Linguistics is not about learning notations.  You can just look at a chart for that.